# What is an Economic Sector?

Tags: industrial-organisation

I am of the understanding that an Economy is broken down as follows:

- Traditional;
- Command;
- Market;
- Mixed.

Each Economy being made up of Sectors, which in turn, are made up of Industries.

Simply put, what defines a Sector?  I understand that it is the broad categorisation of its associated Industries but is there some kind of universal criteria that need to be met for a term to be viewed as a Sector?

I say criteria, as I come across many interpretations of what a Sector is.  For example, some sources state that a Sector is made up as follows:

1. Primary;
2. Secondary;
3. Tertiary;
4. Quaternary;
5. Quinary.

Other sources then approach sectors from a sense of ownership as follows:

1. Public/State Sector;
2. Private Sector;
3. Voluntary Sector.

Then there are the other sources who look at Sectors from the view of a Broad Categorisation of Products/Services.  For example:

1. Financial;
2. Healthcare;
3. Hospitality.

As well as terms seemingly being used interchangeably, it also appears that some sources see Sectors as Industries and vice versa.

Any clarity, on the differentiation, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your example of  *Financial/Healthcare/Hospitality* sectors would often be seen as parts of the *[Tertiary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tertiary_sector_of_the_economy)* or *Service sector*.  Your *Public/Private/Voluntary* split is more about ownership.  But the key point is that *[sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_sector)* is being used as a kind of *part*, and that just depends on how you cut up the economy

Answer (score 1):

The division of the economy into sectors is arbitrary, meaning there is no universally accepted division of the economy. It is contextually dependent.